# Im using this Canna Kit Rasperry Pi power supply low voltage warning

Tags: power

[image]

I'm wondering why I'm getting a low voltage warning with it after all it's recommended by so many sites. I do have it in a 5-slot power brick-like extension cable. Does anyone know why I might be getting this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Low Voltage Warning with Anker Power Supply](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133968/low-voltage-warning-with-anker-power-supply)

Answer (score 0):

Believe the warning. The only place you will get low voltage from is the power supply and or the connections. Rest assured it worked great when it left the factory. Follow the manufacturer's recommendations on what to use until you get enough experience to pick your own.

Answer (score -1):

If your using a Pi with a micro usb socket buy the official micro usb power supply:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/micro-usb-power-supply/

If your using a Pi with a usb-c socket buy the official usb-c power supply:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/type-c-power-supply/